# R how to make my package available online

Tags: r

I have developed a R package, and I want to let anyone uses it by calling

```
install.packages(my package name)
```

help?

I tried to search on Google, and I installed some libraries to do that but these libraries make my package corrupted so i thought to ask you maybe you suggest me the best way

i would like if i have my package on github thanks

Comment: Set up a GitHub and put it there.  the devtools package makes installation from there a breeze `install_github`

Comment: What do you mean by `set up a GitHub` (sorry i am not good in GitHub). Plus, you said `install_github`, but i mean to make my package online, not install new package, is that the same with this statement?

Comment: Do you have a GitHub account?  If not get one.  Then you can put your package there.  Then people can use the dev tools package to install your package using the `install_github` function.  You may need to spend some time googling setting up GitHub and working through the problem a bit.

Comment: what do you mean by `put your package there`? do you mean copy /paste (update my package)?  or i can do that from R studio?

Comment: plus there is something important, i would like the users to use `install.packages` not `install_github`

Comment: I think you really need to send some time reading and googling about GitHub.  There's a ton of stuff about getting started  This really is not the proper forum to discuss these matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best thing to do would be to go over to [GitHub](http://www.github.com) and do some reading.  You mention in the comments that you want the user to be able to use `install.packages()` and **not** `install_github()`. For that you'll need to either submit your package to CRAN or make the tarball source available for download somewhere so that the user can install from source after download.

The [CRAN Repository Policy](http://cran.r-project.org/submit.html) is a good thing to read, as well as [Writing R Extentions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) and of course all the info at GitHub.

By the way, `devtools::install_github()` is very widely used, so you may want to rethink your stance on only using `install.packages()` if not submitting to CRAN.

Comment: `install.packages()` works for any repo, and you can create repos easily.  There is a deeper difference between `install.packages()` (which uses _releases_ an author has provided in a repo) and `install_github()` which (by default) takes a chance at whatever possibly-random state the repo may be in.

Comment: I did what you told me and I was successfully able to upload my package to github. however, I am still not able to download it remotely using install.githug, could you check my new question please?

Answer (score 3):

> I have developed a R package, and I want to let anyone uses it 
>   by calling
>
> `install.packages(my package name)`
>
> help?

That is precisely what [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) is for.  It lets you create a *repository* and by far 
the easiest way is just to let GitHub host it.  The package vignettes detail how.

See the [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) documentation, or the [blog posts about it](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/code/drat/).  Also that we discussed just today [in the r-packages-devel list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2015q2/thread.html) how drat can help as an `additional_repostitories` even for CRAN packages.

Comment: I did what you told me and I was successfully able to upload my package to github. however, I am still not able to download it remotely using install.githug, could you check my new question please?

Comment: I answered your question on about how to provide a package for `install.packages()`.  That is in my view the better question/answer.  Everybody else was just shouting at you to use `install_github()` which is not the same, but this is not the place to discuss the differences -- see the [drat FAQ](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat/blob/master/vignettes/DratFAQ.Rmd) on that.