# How can I use dependency packages that are not located on usual repositories while building a new package?

Tags: r, build, package

My package depends on another package which is not uploaded in cran, mran or even github and it has a .zip format. When submitting my package on cran it can't find the package and returns errors. How can I use the not uploaded package on public repositories, in a package that want to be submitted on cran?

Comment: `install.packages("package.zip",repos=NULL)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install package without internet: error in install.packages: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526286/install-package-without-internet-error-in-install-packages-no-such-file-or-dir)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. The question is not how to install a package that is not on CRAN, but instead how to declare a non-CRAN package as a dependency for a package submitted to CRAN.

Comment: You say that the package isn't available on public repositories?  If that's the case then I don't think your package should be on CRAN.  How exactly would one install your package if they can't access the other package?  Why do you want your package on CRAN if this is the case? And if it isn't please explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Ask the authors of the original package to submit it to CRAN.
2. If the package is open source, add it into your package and attribute the original authors (should probably add them as authors on the combined package; also would be a good idea to contact them first)
3. Create a [drat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=drat) repository for the dependent package and then add this repository in the field `Additional_repositories` in the `DESCRIPTION` file

The 3rd option is the only purely technical solution. See the [drat documentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html), this [SO answer from the drat package author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30419154/2483477), and this [thread on R-pkg-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2015q2/000002.html) in which an R package author successfully submits to CRAN following this strategy.

**Update:** The CRAN package discussed above that used option 3 was [wikipediatrend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wikipediatrend/index.html). This [line in the DESCRIPTION file](https://github.com/petermeissner/wikipediatrend/blob/1d4d8ccd8f99395d32dc99977951d24ab1d9c651/DESCRIPTION#L40) sets the `Additional_repositories` field.

Comment: Thank you very much @John Blischak

Comment: Thanks for the `drat` shoutout, but note that you can have a `Suggests:` on package located in an extra repo reached via the `Additonal_repositories` field.

Comment: Thanks for following up, Dirk. Just to clarify, you are saying that the `Additional_repositories` field can only be used for packages in Suggests, but not Imports or Depends. Is this written somewhere in a manual? The note about `Additional_repositories` in Writing R Extensions doesn't mention this limitation: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies